# Haskell, Don't know why this has a *parse error on input ‘if’*

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

This is to take a number, get its factorial and double it, however because of the base case if you input 0 it gives 2 as the answer so in order to bypass it i used an if statement, but get the error
parse error on input ‘if’. Really appreciate if you guys could help :)

```
fact :: Int -> Int
fact 0 = 1
fact n = n * fact(n-1)

doub :: Int -> Int
doub r = 2 * r

factorialDouble :: IO()
factorialDouble = do 
                    putStr "Enter a Value: "
                    x <- getLine
                    let num = (read x) :: Int
                        if (num == 0) then error "factorial of zero is 0"
                            else let y = doub (fact num) 
                                    putStrLn ("the double of factorial of " ++ x ++ " is " ++ (show y))
```

Comment: Did you mix tabs and spaces?

Comment: The factorial of zero is 1 (you got this right in the definition of `fact`) which means that 2 is the correct answer.

Comment: @Franky The code uses tabs, but does not mix them with spaces (except for the initial 4 spaces for the SO code format) - you can check this in the edit form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've spotted two issues
that should be addressed

1. You have a `let` that has no continuation:
   (`else let y = doub (fact num) ...`).
   Because you're not inside a `do`, you would probably want to change it into a `let ... in` statement.
2. Your `if` is indented too far in. It should be under the `let`.

I've corrected what I mentioned and the code works for me...

```
fact :: Int -> Int
fact 0 = 1
fact n = n * fact(n-1)

doub :: Int -> Int
doub r = 2 * r

factorialDouble :: IO ()
factorialDouble = do 
                    putStr "Enter a Value: "
                    x <- getLine
                    let num = (read x) :: Int
                    if num == 0 then (error "factorial of zero is 0")
                        else let y = doub (fact num) 
                        in putStrLn ("the double of factorial of " ++ x ++ " is " ++ (show y))
```

Comment: No `in` after the `let`?

Comment: On StackOverflow, be sure to mark the correct answer using the check mark next to it.